# Access system clipboard without special registers

Tags: vim

I'm trying to write a set of mappings in vim to yank and put from the vim registers, but without having clipboard support (ie compiled with +clipboard). If not that, then it would be great to have a halfway solution.
So far, I've been able to yank text to `cat`, which prints it at the bottom of the screen for easy selection, but this only works linewise, so if I want to copy a part of a line, I have to `cat` the whole thing.

```
nnoremap <leader>Y V:w !cat<cr>
vnoremap <leader>y :w !cat<cr>
```

I'm wondering if there was some way to use registers, and paste the register contents into `cat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have xclip installed, or some equivalent interface to the system clipboard, then you can use:

```
nnoremap <leader>Y V""Y:call system('xclip -i', @")<cr>
vnoremap <leader>y ""y:call system('xclip -i', @")<cr>
```

Which will yank directly to the system clipboard. You can then use:

```
nnoremap <leader>p :let @" = system('xclip -o')<cr>""p
```

To put from the clipboard.

If you want to stick with the display-for-selection method, you can use:

```
nnoremap <leader>Y V""Y:echo @"<cr>
vnoremap <leader>Y V""Y:echo @"<cr>
vnoremap <leader>y ""y:echo @"<cr>
```

This will yank to the standard yank register, then put its contents into a window at the bottom of the screen, in the same way as what you have, but with character precision. There is also:

```
:echo system('cat', @")
```

Which is basically a long winded form of `:echo @"`. It simply means, call the system command `'cat'`, then **pipe** it the contents of the `"` register. Note that it isn't being passed as command-line parameters, which would look like `:echo system('cat ' . @")`.